# Trying to understand Repository Pattern with EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently implementing EF6 to replace the ADO connection that currently exists.

I have read articles on why I should/shouldn't use the Repository pattern.

However I'm still not sure how to correctly call the repository pattern.

My project is layered as:

Presentation

Business Layer

Business Objects

Data Access Layer

Web Services

In the DAL I add my EF6 connection to my DB.
I created a IRepository and Repository classes.

Should the Business Layer be the one to call the Repository class?
If so I'm missing the connection here on how to call it.

Repository class:

```
public class MyRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class 
{
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet;
    protected DbContext _context;

    public MyRepository(DbContext dataContext)
    {
        _context = dataContext;
        DbSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    #region IRepository

    public int Save()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

My goal is to have MyRepository handle the 6 or so tables that I added in EF.

Where I am missing is how to implement this class in my business access layer.

I get the error
'MyEFConn' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

My attempt at implementing it is:

```
MyRepository<"table from EF"> users = new MyRepository<"table from EF">(MyEFConn);
```

Which MyEFConn is my DbContext class..

```
public partial class MyEFConn: DbContext
```

Comment: [You can't use strings as generics...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx). Your error and your question are unrelated

Comment: I'm not passing a string in.  It would be my table/class that I imported from EF.  Such as MyCar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get the error 'MyEFConn' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

This is because the constructor for MyRepository expects to be passed an instance of a DbContext.  In your case that would be an instance of MyEFConn.

Ex:

```
MyEfConn context = new MyEfConn();
MyRepository<MyUsers> users = new MyRepository<MyUsers>(context);
```